# How to conditionally query tables based on oData request in an Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, conditional-statements, expression, odata, azure-logic-apps

I am a total newbie when it comes to both oData and Logic Apps.

My scenario is as follows:

1. I have an Azure SQL database with two tables (daily_stats, weekly_stats) for users
2. I have a Logic App I managed to test successfully but that targets one table, triggered by an HTTP request and initialises a variable using the following expression to get the query

   if(equals(coalesce(trigger()['outputs']?['queries']?['filter'],''),''),'1 eq 1',trigger()['outputs']?['queries']?['filter'])
3. The problem comes with how to query a different table based on what the user passes as an ODATA GET request

I imagine I need a condition and the pseudo code of this would be something like:

1. For daily stats the ODATA query URL would be

```
    https://myproject.logic.azure.com/workflows/some-guid-here/triggers/manual/paths/invoke/daily_stats/api-version=2016-10-01/&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=my-key-here&filter=userid eq 'richard'
```

2. For weekly stats the ODATA query URL would be

```
    https://myproject.logic.azure.com/workflows/some-guid-here/triggers/manual/paths/invoke/weekly_stats/api-version=2016-10-01/&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=my-sig-here&filter=userid eq 'richard'
```

3. If it is daily_stats, it queries the daily_stats stored procedure/table for the user = richard
4. If it is weekly_stats, it queries the weekly_stats stored procedure/table for the user = richard

**Edit: Added an ASCII flow diagram**

```
                   +----------------------+
                   | HTTP ODATA GET       |
                   | Reguest              |
                   |                      |
                   +----------+-----------+
                              |
                              |
                              |
                              |
                              v
                      +-------+---------+
                      |                 |
                      |                 |
                      |                 |
                      |   filter has    |
                      |   daily_stats   |
                      |                 |
                      +-------+---------+
                              |
                              |
                              |
                              |
+-------------+               |                 +--------------+
|             |               |                 |              |
|             |     YES       |        NO       |              |
|   query     +<--------------+-----------------+  query       |
|   daily     |                                 |  monthly     |
|   stats     |                                 |  stats       |
|   table     |                                 |  table       |
|             |                                 |              |
+-------------+                                 +--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a switch action, further more information you could refer to here:[Create switch statements that run workflow actions based on specific values in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-switch-statement).

Below is my sample,   switch statements support only equality operators. If you need other relational operators, such as "greater than", use a [conditional statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-conditional-statement).

[image]

Comment: Thank-you, but how will the incoming ODATA query be structured?

Comment: What do you mean? You mean how to use the `Filter Query` in the sql actions?

Comment: Sorry, I mean, given a ODATA query structured, for example, as follows `https://myproject.logic.azure.com/workflows/some-guid-here/triggers/manual/paths/invoke/daily_stats/api-version=2016-10-01/&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=my-key-here&filter=userid eq 'richard'`, **how would one extract**? and **assign** those values to be available for the condition to be evaluated?

Comment: You mean how to pass the filter to the query action?

Comment: If yes, just pass `triggerOutputs()[''queries]['filter']`.

Comment: Any process on this issue?